# Update columns to min value from a group

Tags: php, mysql

i have database like this

```
 uniqueid |     name    | newid | sirname
----------+-------------+-------+---------
     A1   |     Adam    |  NULL |  Danny 
     A2   |  Adam (Lee) |  NULL |  Danny 
     A5   |  Adam (Koh) |  NULL |  Danny
     B4   |     Bruce   |  NULL |    CK
     B6   |  Bruce (Lee)|  NULL |    CK
```

How can I update all the `newid` to `min(unique id)` **from `group by sirname`**

The result i want:

```
 uniqueid |     name    | newid | sirname
----------+-------------+-------+---------
    A1    |     Adam    |   A1  |  Danny
    A2    |  Adam (Lee) |   A1  |  Danny
    A5    |  Adam (Koh) |   A1  |  Danny
    B4    |     Bruce   |   B4  |   CK
    B6    | Bruce (Lee) |   B4  |   CK
```

Comment: How do you define "minimum" for data that have both digits and letters?

Comment: What is the type of "unique id"?

Comment: min() work for this type of unique id and the unique id is varchar (1 alphabet with 10 numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this UPDATE JOIN

```
UPDATE
    (
        SELECT sirname,MIN(uniqueid) min_uniqueid
        FROM mytable GROUP BY sirname
    ) A
    INNER JOIN mytable B
    USING (sirname)
SET
    B.newid = A.min_uniqueid
;
```

For this query to work very fast, make sure you have a compound index on sirname and uniqueid.

If you do not have such an index, then run this beforehand:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX sirname_uniqueid_ndx (sirname,uniqueid);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table a 
SET    new_id = (SELECT MIN(unique_id) 
                 FROM   table b 
                 WHERE  b.sirname = a.sirname)
```

Comment: this doesn't work, it promt me this 
"#1093 - You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause"

Answer (score -1):

If BD.'s doesn't work, try:

```
Update tableName As a 
  Set newid = 
    (Select uniqueid 
      From tableName As b 
      Where b.sirname = a.sirname 
      Order By uniqueid 
      Limit 1)
```

Comment: The OP wants the `uniqueid` value to be the value of the group  `surname` not the `surname` value for example the `newID` for the `uniqueid = B6` should be `CK` but your solution will make it `B4`, P. S. I am not the downvoter

Comment: @MGA I see your right after checking the expected results again.  At a glance it looked like it was just a copy from one field to the other.  I'll update my answer.